# PHP Loop - Use Last Non-Blank Value from Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, magento

I apologise if this is hard to understand, it's quite difficult to explain and I'm new to PHP development. I have a script which reads a CSV file row by row and stores each row in an array. The CSV file is formatted like so (example of 3 columns):

[image]

These rows are then ran through a loop which exports the products to the Magento API. Please see my code below:

```
<?php
    // Interpret the CSV file and store each row as an array.
    $csv = array();
    $new_csv = array();

    if (FALSE !== $handle = fopen("http://csvfilelink.csv", "r")) {
        while (FALSE !== $row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
            $csv[] = $row;
        }
    }

    foreach ($csv as $row) {
        $new_row = array();
        for ($i = 0, $c = count($csv[0]); $i < $c; ++$i) {
            $new_row[$csv[0][$i]] = $row[$i]; 
        }
        $new_csv[] = $new_row;
    }

    // Create client session.
    $client = new SoapClient('API-URL');
    $sessionId = $client->login('User', 'Pass');

    // Product variables.
    $attributeSets = $client->catalogProductAttributeSetList($sessionId);
    $attributeSet = current($attributeSets);
    $total_rows = count($csv);

    // Create Products from CSV.
    for ($sku = 1, $name = 1, $price = 1, $desc = 1, $table = 1, $qty = 1, $cond = 1, $pos = 1, $image = 1, $brand = 1, $color = 1, $material = 1, $style = 1;
        $sku < $total_rows, $name < $total_rows, $price < $total_rows, $desc < $total_rows, $table < $total_rows, $qty < $total_rows, $cond < $total_rows, $pos < $total_rows, $image < $total_rows, $brand < $total_rows, $color < $total_rows, $material < $total_rows, $style < $total_rows;
        ++$sku, ++$name, ++$price, ++$desc, ++$table, ++$qty, ++$cond, ++$pos, ++$image, ++$brand, ++$color, ++$material, ++$style) {

        if ($new_csv[$sku]['Product SKU'] != '') {
            try {
                // Create product data.
                $client->catalogProductCreate($sessionId, 'simple', $attributeSet->set_id, $new_csv[$sku]['Product SKU'], array(
                    'name' => $new_csv[$name]['Product Name'],
                    'price' => $new_csv[$price]['Price'],
                    'categories' => array(
                        'category' => 'DifferentCategory'
                    ),
                    'description' => $new_csv[$desc]['Product Description (Including HTML)'] . "<br><br>" . $new_csv[$table]['Param table'],
                    'weight' => 1,
                    'status' => 1,
                    'visibility' => 4,
                    'tax_class_id' => 1,
                    'stock_data' => array(
                        'qty' => $new_csv[$qty]['Stock Quantity'],
                        'is_in_stock' => 1
                    ),
                    'additional_attributes' => array(
                        'single_data' => array(
                            array('key' => 'condition', 'value' => $new_csv[$cond]['Condition (Including HTML)']),
                            array('key' => 'brand', 'value' => $new_csv[$brand]['Brand']),
                            array('key' => 'color', 'value' => $new_csv[$color]['Color']),
                            array('key' => 'material', 'value' => $new_csv[$material]['Material']),
                            array('key' => 'style', 'value' => $new_csv[$style]['Style'])
                        )
                    )
                ),0);

                // Add product images.
                $client->catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate($sessionId, $new_csv[$sku]['Product SKU'], array(
                    'file' => array(
                        'content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($new_csv[$image]['Main Image'])),
                        'mime' => 'image/png',
                    ),
                    'position' => $new_csv[$pos]['Image Rank Position'],
                    'types' => array('image')
                ), 0);

                // Echo success message.
                echo '<div class="success_box"><span class="success_box_text"><b>Success:</b> Product <b>' . $new_csv[$sku]['Product SKU'] . '</b> has been created.</div>';
            } catch (SoapFault $e) {
                // Echo error message.
                echo '<div class="error_box"><span class="error_box_text"><b>Error:</b> Cannot create product <b>' . $new_csv[$sku]['Product SKU'] . '</b> - ' . $e->getMessage() . '.</span></div>';
            }
        } else {
            $client->catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate($sessionId, $new_csv[$sku]['Product SKU'], array(
                'file' => array(
                    'content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($new_csv[$image]['Main Image'])),
                    'mime' => 'image/png',
                ),
                'position' => $new_csv[$pos]['Image Rank Position'],
                'types' => array('image')
            ), 0);
        }
    }

?>
```

This works great for products that only have 1 product image but I realised that I would need to handle rows that only have the `Product Image` column populated as these images will need to be added to the same product that was previously created when `catalogProductCreate` was executed in the previous loop. To attempt to handle this I added an `if/else` statement which identifies if the current value from the `Product SKU` column is empty and then if it is not empty, to only execute the `catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate` code.

The issue with this is that the loop increments the `$sku` variable and therefore when the `else` statement is executed, the script is attempting to add the image to the current value of the `Product SKU` column within the same row and therefore throwing an invalid data error.

I can't work out how to have the script return to the last non-empty `Product SKU` value so that it adds the image to that product instead of returning an error. I may have to remove the `if/else` statement as retrospectively this doesn't handle the problem in the way that I initially hoped it would (stupidly not realising that the variables were going to be incremented with each loop). However I imagine that the `if ($new_csv[$sku]['Product SKU'] != '')` line will still be required somewhere else for this to work.

I'm open to any ideas of how I can overcome this. I thank you in advance for any insight you can offer. Please let me know if this is unclear and needs clarification, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code :)

## 1. Source data

```
<?php

$data = [
  ['1', 'Product1', 'value1.1'],
  ['',   '',        'value1.2'], // there is no value on columns 0 & 1 => take last with
  ['',   '',        'value1.3'], // there is no value on columns 0 & 1 => take last with
  ['2', 'Product2', 'value2.1'],
  ['',   '',        'value2.2'], /// idem
];

?>
```

Extract your own ones via your CSV functions

## 2. Read data

After, you can choose a logic:

- take the previous value with a correct one, for each column
- take the previous value with a correct one, where the ID column is valid (for ex).
- ...

I will answer for the first :)

```
<?php
/**************************************************************
 * FUNCTION getPreviousColumnValue                            *
 **************************************************************
 * This function return the previous valid value on array     *
 * list, on the selected colum. A valid value is something    *
 * not null or different of '' (empty).                       *
 **************************************************************
 * @param array $data: array source, multidim                 *
 * @param int $from: current line. Will extract sub array     *
 * from 0 to $from.                                           *
 * @param int $column: column index to analyze.               *
 **************************************************************
 * Examples:                                                  *
 *  - getPreviousColumnValue($data, 3, 0)                     *
 *     On $data, from line 3, return the previous  correct    *
 *     value for column 0 on $data array                      *
 **************************************************************/
function getPreviousColumnValue(array $data, $from, $column) {
    $data = array_slice($data, 0, $from + 1); // extract sub data array. $from id the current line
    $data = array_reverse($data); // reverse for analyze

    // Loop on each reversed line (from 0 to $from)
    foreach( $data as $row ) {
        // If the index does not exist, skip
        if( !isset($row[$column]) ) continue;

        // If the value (is null or empty) and different of '0', skip
        if( is_null($row[$column]) OR $row[$column] === '' ) continue;

        // Else, return this value !
        return $row[$column];
    }
    return null; // Null, there is no value :(
}

// Read CSV data - this is your code !
foreach( $data as $iLineNumber => $line ) {

    // Include this loop at the begenning of you code
    // Iterate on each row of the line:
    foreach( $line as $iRowKey => $row ) {
        // If the value (is null or empty) and different of '0' ...
        // ... we need to find the previous valid value
        if( is_null($row) OR $row === '' ) {
            $line[$iRowKey] = getPreviousColumnValue($data, $iLineNumber, $iRowKey);
        }
        // So, if value is valid => use it ; else, find correct one via the function
    }
    
    // Your code here ! The array is fully filled.
    // $client->catalogProductCreate(...)
    var_dump($line);
}
```

With the final output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string 'Product1' (length=8)
  2 => string 'value1.1' (length=8)

array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string 'Product1' (length=8)
  2 => string 'value1.2' (length=8)

array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string 'Product1' (length=8)
  2 => string 'value1.3' (length=8)

array (size=3)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => string 'Product2' (length=8)
  2 => string 'value2.1' (length=8)

array (size=3)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => string 'Product2' (length=8)
  2 => string 'value2.2' (length=8)
```

This is what you need ?

Comment: Thank you so much for adding this. Excuse my ignorance, but what is the first block of code for? I think it will take me some time to understand this but I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I added some comments on the previous post. It's better ? :)

Comment: Really appreciate the time you took to write this, thank you :) Regarding `// Read CSV data - this is your code !` should I change the name of my variables to match yours? `foreach ($csv as $row)` to `foreach( $data as $iLineNumber => $line )`

Comment: You can adapt to your code now. Of course you can change the variable, but be careful: maybe I already used them.: `foreach( $line as $iRowKey => $row )` => $row is already used just after :). Maybe just change `$data` to `$csv` ?

Comment: Sorry for the questions, this has got me a bit lost. So am I removing my entire `foreach` loop and replacing it with the `foreach` loop that you have here? Apologies, I'm very new to PHP but once I understand something then I remember the logic for good.

Comment: Put your code from your `for` where there is the comment `put your code here` and replace your variable `$new_csv` by my variable `$line`. Does not forget to add your variable initialization (client, sessionid, ...) before the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130294/discussion-between-matt136-and-georges-o).