# set fixed string value until next detected change in foreach php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a CSV with data like this:
(for some reason table doesn't display properly after I publish question, so here is screenshot from question edit screen)
[image: CSV]
Im trying to convert it into array to have data like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => PRODUCTID1
            [name] => HONDA
            [country] => JAPANESE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => PRODUCTID2
            [name] => TOYOTA
            [country] => JAPANESE
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [code] => PRODUCTID3
            [name] => NISSAN
            [country] => JAPANESE
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [code] => PRODUCTID4
            [name] => BMW
            [country] => GERMAN
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [code] => PRODUCTID5
            [name] => AUDI
            [country] => GERMAN
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [code] => PRODUCTID6
            [name] => MERCEDES
            [country] => GERMAN
        )
)
```

How do I set $country string to be same for every line until next detected change?

Obviuosly putting this inside foreach loop doesn't work as it searches and sets value on every line:

```
if (strpos(strtolower(trim($value[1])), 'japanese') === true) {
    $country = 'japanese';
}
elseif (strpos(strtolower(trim($value[1])), 'german') === true) {
    $country = 'german';
}
```

this is my code:

```
function csv_content_parser($content) {
  foreach (explode("\n", $content) as $line) {
    yield str_getcsv($line, ",");
  }
}

$content = file_get_contents('cars.csv');

// Create one array from csv file's lines.
$data = array();
foreach (csv_content_parser($content) as $fields) {
  array_push($data, $fields);
}

$naujas_array = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

    if (!empty($value[0])) {
            $naujas_array[] =  array(
            'code'              => $value[0], 
            'name'              => $value[1], 
            'country'           => $country);
    }   
}
print_r($naujas_array);
```

Comment: Can you provide the csv content itself ?

Comment: Very related: [Value of previous row in CSV import via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50116404/2943403) and [PHP Loop - Use Last Non-Blank Value from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41074228/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with an empty `$country`, and if `$value[0]` is empty, change it:

```
$country = null;

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

    if (!empty($value[0])) {
            $naujas_array[] =  array(
            'code'              => $value[0], 
            'name'              => $value[1], 
            'country'           => $country);
    } else {
        $country = $value[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the extra `foreach()` loop to push data from your generator into the temporary `$data` array.

Loop over your generator data and destructure each row into intuitive variables (`$code` and `$name`).

Use a functionless condition to determine if the `$code` value is empty.  If so, cache the `$name` value as the `$country`.  If not, form an associative row with `compact()` and push that data into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/16lHR))

```
$result = [];
$country = null;
foreach (csv_content_parser($content) as [$code, $name]) {
    if (!$code) {
        $country = $name;
    } else {
        $result[] = compact(['code', 'name', 'country']);
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Or `continue` to avoid the `else` branch and minimize code tabbing/width. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1Ao2o))

```
$result = [];
$country = null;
foreach (csv_content_parser($content) as [$code, $name]) {
    if (!$code) {
        $country = $name;
        continue;
    }
    $result[] = compact(['code', 'name', 'country']);
}
var_export($result);
```

Comment: Why confuse researchers by giving a correct, educational, demonstrated answer a negative score?